# Comparator resolving input voltages close to vdd

Tags: comparator, input

I have a design problem to solve. The problem statement goes as follows:
"Design a clocked comparator resolving input voltages close to vdd dissipating less than 100 uA".

What does "resolving input voltages close to vdd" mean? Does it mean that if the input voltage is close to vdd then the output should go to vss, depending on the reference voltage? It would be nice if you guys could explain it to me with an example.

Comment: Is this something your professor ask you? If so, have you asked them?

Comment: Take a look at a comparator datasheet. Any comparator datasheet.

Comment: @KingDuken Yes it is a homework problem, however i dont have access to the proff now, it is too late, and the deadline is tomorrow.

Comment: @Toor Went through TI comparator datasheet, they all talk about resolution which i understand and the error, nothing about resolving voltages

Comment: Pay more attention to the common-mode input range. You're probably unknowingly making sweeping false assumptions about what it is for every op-amp. If my eyes can distinguish billions of colours but get blinded by a night light, I ain't distinguishing nothin'.

Comment: It (probably) means that you need to design a comparator that will work with input voltages close to VDD.  "Close" is in the eye of the beholder, but within 1V is good, within 0.1V is better, and inclusive of VDD or even a bit (0.1V) above is better yet.

Comment: If you use W/L = 1/10 for the input FET diffpair, this may be easy.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I think what @TimWescott said is probably correct. The idea is to have input voltages close to supply without pushing the MOS out of saturation. As regards to the exam, i failed :( since i could not get a sufficient gain for the comparator to work. Back to the basics.